# 2 dimension layout only using floats

Tags: html, css, layout, frontend

I'm kind of stuck, I'm trying to create this layout only using floats as a part of #100devs program.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmAIW.jpg)

However I can get the left and center image from the 2nd row to occupy the available space in top of them.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfaoS.jpg)

Here's the code - HTML:

```
<section class="row container lookbook">
        <h2>OUR LOOKBOOK</h2>
        <div class="container lookbook-container">
            <section class="clearfix">
                <img src="assets/img/Gallery-01-150x150.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="assets/img/Masonry-01.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="assets/img/Gallery-02-150x150.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="assets/img/Masonry-02.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="assets/img/Masonry-03.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="assets/img/Gallery-04-150x150.jpg" alt="">
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
/* Lookbook */
.lookbook-container img {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

Any ideas? Thanks!
```

I tried with the code block that is shown in the question part, tried clearing floats and even playing with margins and padding to give the img for space to go up